# Primeng's p-multiselect onFilter is not working properly

Tags: angular, filter, primeng, multi-select

API and SP is working Perfectly fine. I am getting the response of 10 rows. Also I have console the array which is bind to multiselect , it is also showing proper 10 records But nothing is reflecting in search drop down : 0 records,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPjye.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nLQF.png)

Images are attached above.

I have written below code for the HTMl :

```
<p-multiSelect [(ngModel)]="selectedErpLineIdOptions" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                            [options]="erpTempLineMulti" appendTo="body" [style]="{'minWidth':'100% !important' }"
                            filterPlaceholder=" Select ERP Lines " (onFilter)="reLoadErpLineDrpData($event)"
                            defaultLabel="{{ 'plantHierarchyLineComponent.ERPline' | translate}}"
                            emptyFilterMessage=" {{ 'inspectionProcessManager.classNotFOund' | translate}}"
                            optionLabel="name" (onChange)="onSelectedErpLineItem($event)"
                            display="chip"></p-multiSelect>
```

I have given a TS call on (onFilter) event. below is the code  for that.

```
this.authService.getData(`${this.jsonService.appConfig.commonUrl}/APIURLWithSearchParameter`).subscribe((data) => {
      this.erpTempLineMulti = [];
      this.erpLineTemp = JSON.parse(data);
      this.erpLineTemp.forEach(e => {
        this.erpTempLineMulti.push({
          id: e.id,
          name: e.name,
          lineId: this.inputId == undefined || this.inputId == null ? 0 : this.inputId,
          organizationId: e.organizationId
        });
      })
      console.log(this.erpTempLineMulti)
});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors, it should work, I have created a test here where a simulated wait with 3 sec, before data arrives, and it works fine [stackblitz MRE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-demo-ac9bdf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: No errors at all.

Comment: @NilsKähler , I tried with setTimeOut as well but nothing fruitful

Comment: @NilsKähler , Also (onFilter) is not there is the example you specified.

Comment: You need to create a MRE, try to expand the MRE I created with the relevant methods, that are missing, and then I can take a look at what is happening, I can't help you without knowing all the relevant code. Have you tried to remove the filter function and see if your code then works?